# Not able to ping between 2 Laptop

Tags: networking

I have connected 2 laptop at home to share files between them having window 7. I have connected both of them with a straight over cable and gave IP Address as follows : 192.168.0.1 and other one has 192.168.0.2. The problem is i am not able to ping each other. It gives following error : host not reachable.

Comment: This is off-topic here and should be asked on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because ICMP echo replies are not enabled by default on Windows 7 i.e. it doesn't answer to ping. You have to [follow](https://marcowuen.wordpress.com/2012/09/15/solved-windows-7-client-ignores-ping-requests/) these steps to enable it:

- From the Start menu, search for Windows Firewall with Advanced
  Security. Click it.
- From the left pane, click Inbound Rules.
- Look for Networking – Echo Request (ICMPv4-In)
- Activate the rule